# Rounding of an integer multiplied by a decimal

Tags: computational-mathematics

Had a question regarding numerical rounding that I hope can be answered. Is there anyway to prove the following:

```
For any non-zero constant a, prove that x - round(round(x * a) * (1/a)) == 0
```

I have been playing with the case in python with:

```
for x in range(0, 1000000):
  y = round(x * (1.2))
  z = round(y * (1/1.2))
  if z != x:
     print(x)
```

which never prints, which got me wondering if there is a possible proof for this. Thanks!

edit: to be clear, this is the python3 round method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

and this would only be for positive and real x and a, both >= 1

Comment: I wonder if you can define "round" more clearly?

Comment: This has a chance of being true when $a\ge 1$, but try $x=1$, $a=0.01$...

Comment: @ssnake Is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the definition of `round` that you are using? "*Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input ...*". If so, you should include that into the question, since not everybody here is familiar with the python libraries.

Comment: This is a math site, so we think $x$ and $a$ are reals, not computer numbers.  Your statement is clearly false for $x$ not an integer if round returns an integer as I suspect.  Please specify what type of number $x$ and $a$ are, that you are using computer multiply, etc.  -1

Comment: thanks all, sorry for the missing detals

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it because it isn't true.  round(something) is an integer, so if $x$ is not an integer the left side is not zero.